# Authorization in ruby app without rails

Tags: ruby, authentication, authorization

I'm trying to develop a ruby application that will be running as web service to provide some information stored at its database. So guests must be able to GET information but, as soon as I won`t have anything to register users, they can't do nothing else (PUT, DELETE, UPDATE..).
It's a simple app that doesn't need Rails, but a I must avoid any attempt from bots or no good intention people who try to change things in this DB. I'm the only one who can make changes such as updates in this DB.

Does anybody has any kind of tip for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails controller is what determines the access a request can do:

Let's say you had a products controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @products = Product.all

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html  # index.html.erb
       format.json  { render :json => @products }
     end
  end

  def show
    ## Retrieve the product...
  end
end
```

This only provides information for all products and one particular product

In your routes just allow index and show

```
resources :products, :only => [:index, :show]
```

The only access is to see all the products and a particular product, there is no way to create or edit.

Comment: although i didn't wanted to use rails, only ruby, your answer seems to be quite simple and functional. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what kind of usability requirements you have, you could theoretically make any changes you wanted in the database manually using the `rails dbconsole`. Then you don't need any authorization at all.